# How to get data from font on python

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, ttx-fonttools

on js we used to get data via https://github.com/dy/font-measure

```
ascender: 0.95
capHeight: 0.89
height: (fontData.ascender - fontData.descender) * -1;//1.4
median: 0.47
```

but have no idea how to get those value on python tried

```
        from PIL import ImageFont

        text = 'sphinx'
        H = 100
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font, H, encoding='utf-8')
        ascent, descent = font.getmetrics()
        (width, baseline), (offset_x, offset_y) = font.font.getsize(text)
```

but I can't get the numbers quite right and am not sure what is what. any help on this will be appreciated.

images:
js one :
[image: js image]
python one -i think?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounding box with [`font.getbbox("text", anchor="ls")`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getbbox) (the [anchor](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/text-anchors.html) indicates you are interested in coordinates relative to the left-baseline point) and the advance length with [`font.getlength("text")`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getlength). You already have the maximum ascent and descent values from [`font.getmetrics()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getmetrics). The line height is `font.font.height`. The cap height and x height are not available via Pillow, but you could try `-font.getbbox("A", anchor="ls")[1]` for the cap height and `-font.getbbox("x", anchor="ls")[1]` for the x height.

You might be interested in reading the [text anchor documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/text-anchors.html) in detail.